# access denied page using spring security not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using the below configuration for access denied page

```
 <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/noAccess"/>
```

and then mapped /noAccess to the controller. but when I try to access resource to which i dont have access I get an error page

HTTP Status 404 - /mycontext/noAccess in the browser

though when I type the whole url http://abc.mycompany:8080/mycontext/noAccess I can see the error page. any idea why spring is not redirecting to the controller ?

Comment: Did you add a security rule on the `noAccess` uri so that it's available to anyone?

Comment: I don't think that is required, if not specified the resource is available to all

Answer (score 0):

I am using below configuration for access denied page in my project and it is working for me.

Make changes according to your need.

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/accessDenied.jsp">

        <security:form-login login-page="/index.jsp"
            default-target-url="/jsp/home.jsp" />


        <security:intercept-url pattern="/jsp/listInBetweenPlaces.jsp"
            access="permitAll" />
</security:http>
```

Comment: thanks, now I get the default HTTP 403 error page(the browser default), it still not showing my application specific error page

Comment: 1. just check if any View Resolver is there and path is created by that for access denied page. 2. check access denied page is kept to be permissible by all by making <security:intercept-url pattern="/noAccess" access="permitAll" />.

Comment: tried no change, I am using tiles for resolving views. but it seems the access-denied-page is not going through the normal flow.

Comment: can you post your security xml file.

Comment: <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
  
 <security:http entry-point-ref="spnegoEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/noAccess"> </security:http>
   <security:intercept-url pattern="/noAccess" access="permitAll" /> <security:intercept-url pattern="/project" access="hasAnyRole('TIM|TIM_ADMIN')"/></security:http>

Comment: not very sure, isn't  <security:intercept-url> tag will come inside <security:http> tag? try once.

Comment: that's right, please ignore it was a copy&paste error, the promblem still remains

Comment: enable spring logs and check what actually happens for that request.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your bean configuration.

```
  <mvc:view-controller path="/uncaughtException"/>
  <mvc:view-controller path="/resourceNotFound"/>
  <mvc:view-controller path="/dataAccessFailure"/>

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver"    p:defaultErrorView="uncaughtException">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key=".DataAccessException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
            <prop key=".NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".TypeMismatchException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            <prop key=".MissingServletRequestParameterException">resourceNotFound</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Create the following pages and add these to Context folder

```
     resourceNotFound.jsp
     uncaughtException.jsp
     dataAccessFailure.jsp
```